# Win Server 2008 R2 - Task Scheduler - Elevate access level and stay in user environment

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to run a powershell script at logon for each user account with the username `User`. The purpose of the script is to call the `qwinsta` command and further identify which session it is currently being used on, along with other client information.

Using Task Scheduler, it's easy to setup a login task for this script. However, the user is logged in with account `User`, which is denied access to use Powershell in any shape or form. To counter this, I must set the task up to run as a higher access level account, `Support`. This is fine, but the `qwinsta` command will return the `Support` account as the current session logged into the `User` account, if `Support` is already logged in. Otherwise, it returns session name `services`. This defeats the purpose of the script!

In the ideal situation,

- `User` logs into the server
- a logon task is run with `Support` level access, getting information from `User`'s environment.

Comment: im not entirely sure, i have never really restricted the access to cmd or powershell, but if you make it a logon script using the GPO's would it not run as intended?

Comment: @Kage GPO = Group Policy Object?